# Laravel 8 confirm-password route don't respect overridden URL from ForceRootURL

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I'm using forceRootURL on my RouteServiceProvider to change all my URLs in my Laravel 8 app, using the code below under parent::boot():

```
        // Force laravel to use APP_URL as root url for the app.
        $strBaseURL = $this->app['url'];
        $strBaseURL->forceRootUrl(config('app.url'));

        if (\Str::contains(\Config::get('app.url'), 'https://')) {
            \URL::forceScheme('https');
        }
```

I've set APP_URL on my .env file to a https subfolder, and with exception of confirm-password route and pagination methods, everything still works OK. Both keeps redirecting to URLs without the APP_URL root URL, breaking the application.

I've been looking for a solution using mainly the resources offered by the framework itself, without defining custom helpers, or extensively complex methods or classes, because I believe it's a matter of misguiding from mine (I'm working with Laravel from less than a year). But if there´s no easy solution I'll accept everything.

I really appreciate some help, and thanks in advance.

Update: I believe it's a problem with the redirect() method, but I still don't know the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have changed the `APP_URL` in your .env file & ran `php artisan config:clear` then you can add into your `app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php`  within the boot method:

```
\URL::forceRootUrl(\Config::get('app.url'));
```

The scheme stuff is deprecated, I believe.

Comment: I changed the AppServiceProvider and unfortunately the issue persists. And how I handle https requests without forceScheme?